# Issue with SQL command and/or Opencart 1.5.6.4

Tags: php, sql, opencart

I need to filter products by part of their Model code in my Opencart web shop , therefore I edited the product.php file so that these lines:

```
$sql .= " AND p.model LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_model']) . "%'";
```

are now:

```
$sql .= " AND p.model LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_model']) . "%'";
```

Now the searches for parts of product codes work, but a whole subcategory of products is not shown even if I search for the exact Model code.

I've looked in the subcategory settings and found nothing useful as to why just this subcat gets excluded.

Is this linked to what I've modified in the code above? Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Undo your amendment! Does the subcategory stuff start working again?

Comment: That change would not have affected the results in the way you described.